# Loader when confirm clicked in metamask

Tags: metamask, meta-transactions, sendtransaction

I want to add a loader to UI when there is a click on confirm transaction popup on metamask. When user clicks on confirm I want to show the loader until the transaction is confirmed. Is there a way to handle this?? Is there any event??

Answer (score 0):

Ethers.js has a very simple solution for this question:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

let tx = await contract.method(...)
let txConfirm = await provider.getTransaction(tx.hash)
///perform operation only after "Confirm" is clicked in MetaMask
```

See docs on provider.getTransaction() here:
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/provider/-%23-Provider-getTransactionReceipt